# Invalid argument: specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to run a model exported from Keras in Tensorflow using the C++ API. The model is exported and imported correctly, however when I try to run the session in C++, the names of the variables I pass in the `Run` member of `tensorflow::Session` get modified, causing the error:

```
Invalid argument: Tensor Output0:0, specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph
```

Here is the model I have built in Keras:

```py
S = Input(shape=[state_size], name='Input')
h0 = Dense(self.HIDDEN1_UNITS, name='Hidden1', kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.RandomUniform())(S)
h0_a = Activation('relu')(h0)
h1 = Dense(self.HIDDEN2_UNITS, name='Hidden2', kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.RandomUniform())(h0_a)
h1_a = Activation('relu')(h1)
output = Dense(1)(h1_a)
output_a = Activation('tanh', name='Output0')(output)
model = Model(S,output_a)
```

The model is exported using `tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util`
and `tensorflow.python.framework.graph_io`, following the approach implemented in https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow

The model is then imported in Tensorflow using the C++ API:

```cc
ParseProtoUnlimited(&graph_def, <graph_protoprotobuffer>, <graph_size> );
```

The graph seems to be imported successfully, in fact when I print the nodes name contained in the graph in Tensorflow I get the following:

```
Names : Input_5
Names : Hidden1_5/kernel
Names : Hidden1_5/kernel/read
Names : Hidden1_5/bias
Names : Hidden1_5/bias/read
Names : Hidden1_5/MatMul
Names : Hidden1_5/BiasAdd
Names : activation_5_1/Relu
Names : Hidden2_5/kernel
Names : Hidden2_5/kernel/read
Names : Hidden2_5/bias
Names : Hidden2_5/bias/read
Names : Hidden2_5/MatMul
Names : Hidden2_5/BiasAdd
Names : activation_6_1/Relu
Names : dense_3_1/kernel
Names : dense_3_1/kernel/read
Names : dense_3_1/bias
Names : dense_3_1/bias/read
Names : dense_3_1/MatMul
Names : dense_3_1/BiasAdd
Names : Output_5/Tanh
Names : output0
```

Now, if I want to try and run the session, I do the following:

```cc
Tensor input(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape( { 4 }));
...
[init tensor]
...
session->Run({{"Input_5", input}}, {"Output0"}, {},
                &outputs);
```

But the application throws the following error:

```
Invalid argument: Tensor Output0:0, specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph
```

Why the function Run session appends the :0 to the output tensor I want to retrieve?

Also, I have tried beforehand to do the above with a simple graph built with Tensorflow, and the session on C++ run with no problem. Here is the graph that worked:

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.Variable(5.0, name='a')
    b = tf.Variable(6.0, name='b')
    c = tf.multiply(a, b, name="c")
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    exported = sess.graph_def.SerializeToString()
    size = sess.graph_def.ByteSize()
```

```cc
Tensor a(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape());
a.scalar<float>()() = 5.0;

Tensor b(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape());
b.scalar<float>()() = 6.0;

std::vector<std::pair<string, tensorflow::Tensor>> inputs = {
                { "a", a }, { "b", b }, };

std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;
Run the session, evaluating our "c" operation from the graph
status = session->Run(inputs, { "c" }, { }, &outputs);
```

Why in the second case I manage to run the session whereas in the first case I get that error?

Keras version is `2.2.2`
Tensorflow version is `1.11.0`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your 'Output0' variable is lowercase.

Comment: Also having same issues in running a model with c++. How did you print layer names ?